# Android 9: Ethernet and Wifi simulataneously

Tags: java, android

I have a scenario where I want to use wifi to connect to the internet (comfortably via androids settings) and ethernet for accessing local network which is not connected to the internet.

Thus I want to have both ethernet and wifi up simultaneously and use the routing table to send all the local requests to the ethernet and the default to wifi.

I found out android disables wifi when ethernet is enabled...
There has been a fix for an old android version on https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/pie-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java

Problem: In Android 9 the file looks different and I cannot find the lines mentioned...
I am using a Khadas Vim3 and their android build.

Can you please help me, which lines need to be changed?
This is the file:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-c2f2-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2492861: you said a few years ago that you did the same... can you please help?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?? I am facing the same issue with Android 10 AOSP

Comment: No, unfortuanetly I did not find a solution, but implemented a virtual openwrt instance which takes care of it.